# Including multiple animations in a single animation

Tags: android, animation

I have a view that I'm animating with the following animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to put multiple operations in this set block so that I can have a different type of animation happen before the alpha one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's precisely what the animation set is for:

> Represents a group of Animations that should be played together. The
>   transformation of each individual animation are composed together into
>   a single transform. If AnimationSet sets any properties that its
>   children also set (for example, duration or fillBefore), the values of
>   AnimationSet override the child values.

You can include different animations in the set and control when they happen with their start time and duration.

Comment: Ok, so how do I control their start times?